# Function satisfies differential equation.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, distribution-theory

Given the D'Alembert operator [D'Alembertian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert_operator) $\Box$, I want to show that

$$
G(x,t,x_0,t_0):= \frac{\delta \left(t_0 + \frac{||x-x_0||}{c} -t \right)}{||x-x_0||}
$$

satisfies

$$
\Box G(x,t,x_0,t_0) = - 4 \pi  \delta(x-x_0)\delta(t-t_0)
$$

Does anybody know if there is a nice way to see that this is true?

Comment: Oh, that is very different than what I thought you were writing before. The problem was mostly a misunderstanding of notation, my apologies.

Comment: no problem, thank you for looking at this :-)